# Moving content of csv to different column in stringbuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csv

I am trying to export data into a csv. Everything works fine, however, my output is put in one column. It nicely moves to next lines and so on, but I have no idea how to put it in new columns. Also, I cannot predefine number of columns, as this depends on the database. I am almost sure there is a tiny little thing that I should change.

```
StringBuilder csvContent = new StringBuilder();
ClassDeclarationsDBEntities entities6 = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities();
var subj = entities6.Subjects.Where(a => a.class_id == model.class_id).FirstOrDefault();
csvContent.AppendLine(subj.name.ToString());
csvContent.Append("Name,Surname");

foreach (var task in current)
{
    csvContent.Append(task.name.Replace(" ",string.Empty)+",");
}

csvContent.AppendLine("Total");

foreach (var user in curr_users)
{
    if (user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 1.ToString())
    {
        csvContent.Append(user.name.Replace(" ", String.Empty) + ",");
        csvContent.Append(user.surname.Replace(" ", String.Empty) + ",");

        foreach (var task in current)
        {
            foreach (var grade in model.grading)
            {    
                if (user.user_id == grade.user_id)
                {
                    if (task.task_id == grade.task_id)
                    {
                        inside = grade.points;
                        i = i + grade.points;}}}  

       csvContent.Append(inside.ToString()+",");
       inside = 0;}
csvContent.AppendLine(i.ToString()+",");}

i = 0;}

byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csvContent.ToString());   
return File(buffer, "application/CSV", "Report.csv");
```

Comment: Excel uses locale list separator. Comma in USA but it might be something else in your country. Check TextInfo.ListSeparator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is that instead of using commas after the column end, I should use ;
This depends on ListSeparators and is dependent on location.